# ADB over wireless without USB

Tags: android, adb, wireless

I know it.s possible to connect with adb to a non-rooted android device by connecting by USB and running the command:
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect {device ip}

But last week my phone got wet and it.s impossible to connect/charge via USB. I can charge it with a wireless charger (it.s a Nexus 4)

So i.m left with a device that works perfectly but it.s not rooted and you can.t connect the USB.

Is there any way I can connect adb via wireless so I can still develop with this phone?

Or is it possible to root my phone without USB? (I rrpeat, i.m using a Nexus 4).

Answer (score 0):

You can use memory card. Install `ClockworkMod` first, copy ROM to memory card, push the card (`sdcard`) to device, flash it via `ClockworkMod`.

Comment: Thank you so much, trying it... But note: Nexus 4 doesn't have a SD-card. I will try pushing the files via Airdroid or similar

Comment: erm... it looks like you need root for ClockworkMod (ROM Manager) to work?

Comment: dang! .. my bad, it definitely requires USB >.< .Or you could try this, http://androidforums.com/thunderbolt-all-things-root/566440-rooting-without-usb-i-know-its-been-posted-before-ive-searched.html